# Get rgb value(0..255) from pixel's HEX

Tags: javascript, hex

Let say i have `0x757575` which is a value of one pixel in HEX containing 8 bits for each red, green and blue, then how do i extract value of red, green and blue separately in javascript?

```
var pixel = 0x757575;
// do i need to split it up into two character each [75,75,75]
// if i do as above, did it already become decimal
```

My use case is, i got already list of pixels from image in array container `[757575, 080808,......]`, and i want to create/render image inside canvas container using `putImageData`'s method from canvas api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some bit math

```js
var pixel = 0x757575;
var red = (pixel & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
var green = (pixel & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
var blue = (pixel & 0x0000FF);
alert(red + "," + green + "," + blue);
```

For the red value, we use a bitmask to yield only the upper two hex values of the pixel value, then shift the result 16 bits to the right, so in our case

```
0x757575 & 0xFF0000 = 0x750000
0x750000 >> 16 = 0x75 (= 117 in decimal)
```

Green is similar, we discard everything but the middle 2 hex values and shift the result 8 bits to the right

```
0x757575 & 0x00FF00 = 0x007500
0x007500 >> 8 = 0x75
```

Blue is just the final 2 bits masked out, no shifting required.

Since this technique uses 100% bit arithmetic it's very efficient.

Resource: [MDN - Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: Cool!.. can you explain i lil bit

Comment: `0x750000 >> 16 ` why 16?

Comment: In hex, each digit holds four bits.  We have four digits (the zeros) to shift, so 4 bits times 4 digits = 16 bits.  Similarly when there are 2 zeros to shift, that's 8 bits.

Comment: ah ha, got that. Thanks james. Need to learn deep down about this

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from hex to rgb using following function -

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
```

`hexToRgb("#757575").r`  outputs  `117`

Comment: i cant pass string to hexToRgb as parameter

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
      function hex2Rgb(hex) {
      var toInt = parseInt(hex, 16);
      var r = (toInt >> 16) & 255;
      var g = (toInt >> 8) & 255;
      var b = toInt & 255;

      return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
  }

  var rgb = hex2Rgb('0x757575');
```

[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/lnzoZruKy6nJFhpjOfn7?p=preview)

Comment: Works perfectly, can you explain i lil bit for my understanding

Comment: `a >>b`  shifts `a` to right `b` bits, and `&255` mask, will take the last 2 bytes shifted. So in turn each of the lines 16/8/0 will give you the relevant byte for r/g/b

Comment: Ok got it, thanks Yuvals for this answer. Appreciated that, will make is a references for me from now